# How to implement JQuery Airport Board Effect

Tags: jquery

I found this interesting effect like the information on a airport: [Flight Board](http://keith-wood.name/flightBoard.html)

I want implement this on my site. I use ASP.NET.
Here is a sample of my database:

```
COUNTRY       DATE
|CHINA     | 2014-04-11 |
|USA       | 2014-04-14 |
|INDIA     | 2014-05-02 |
```

In the sample script I must add my database value into this:

```
$('#basicBoard').flightboard({messages: ['FIRST MESSAGE', 'SECOND MESSAGE'], ... });
```

Comment: why don't you put the values in the messages array itself

Comment: [How should data be passed between client-side Javascript and C# code behind an ASP.NET app?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122357/how-should-data-be-passed-between-client-side-javascript-and-c-code-behind-an-a)